# Firebase emulator hitting DB via the REST feature

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

I’m trying to setup the emulator so I can develop the firebase functions safely before deploying them. I just noticed that some REST calls I’m doing now fails - anybody know if it is not possible to use the REST feature of the RealTime DB https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

I'm trying to hit it with this URL

`http://localhost:9000/?ns=<PROJECT ID>-default-rtdb/development/DISHES.json`

because this is what I set the `firebaseConfig.databaseURL` to (suggested [here](https://youtu.be/pkgvFNPdiEs?t=314) by Google)

Bonus info: If I try to do a GET to the URL via postman it creates another database called `fake-server` (`http://localhost:4000/database/fake-server: null`)

Comment: As far as I know the REST API should work on the emulator. Can you edit your question to show what you've done, and the error you get?

Comment: Sorry about that Frank - forgot it in the haste. Will do it soon

Comment: I have update the question @FrankvanPuffelen - again: sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3), the path must come **before** the query parameters in URLs. Your URL should be instead written as:

```
http://localhost:9000/development/DISHES.json?ns=<PROJECT ID>-default-rtdb
```

Note how the corrected URL has the query parameter appended to the very end. (The URL you've provided in the question will be parsed as having one query parameter `ns` with the value of `<PROJECT ID>-default-rtdb/development/DISHES.json`, which is not a valid namespace name. That explains the errors you've seen.)

---

FYI, it looks like you're constructing the URL by concatenating the string `databaseURL` with the path -- this may lead to surprising results as you've seen above. Considering using a URL parser / formatter in your language / framework of choice instead, which handles URL parts correctly. For example, in JavaScript you can use the snippet below:

```
const url = new URL(databaseURL); // Parse URL (including query params, if any)
url.pathname = '/development/DISHES.json';
yourFetchingLogic(url.toString()); // Reconstruct the URL with path replaced
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and your suggestion on using a URL parser - very useful